# jQuery animation memory issues

Tags: jquery, windows-8, winjs

I have a small (17K) image that I am animating using the jQuery toggle('slow') method. As I watch the memory usage by my application, I am seeing big jumps each time this method is called, especially the first 3 or 4 times. Here are the exact numbers:

- toggle('slow') first call (displays 17k image) - increases by 10.8 Mb
- toggle('slow') second call (hides image) - increases by another 2.5
  Mb
- toggle('slow') third call (displays image) - increases by
  500 K

...and so on with lesser increases, but still increasing. If I just use toggle() without the animation there is no increase in memory usage.

I have seen recommendations to store the element in a variable outside the function calling the toggle('slow') method, but that is not solving the problem. Here is the code:

```
 var $setLoc = $("#setLocation");
 function toggleAll(){
      $setLoc.toggle('slow');
 }
```

Comment: How long before your memory consumption becomes a legitimate problem?

Comment: Is this the same in all browsers or limited to only one?

Comment: I'm at the upperbounds already for memory consumption, so it's already an issue - This is for a Windows 8 Metro app, which runs full screen in a touch-optimized, chrome free version of IE10.

Comment: Anthony - I've tested it in the regular IE10 browser with the same issue, as well as Chrome 19.0.1084.52 on Win 8. Chrome doesn't seem to have the same issue, although it does seem to creep up 5-10K per animation, sometimes releasing it back.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? If you're not going with 1.8 check whether the issue has been resolved: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/09/jquery-1-8-released/
If you're using 1.8 you can try an earlier version to see whether the issue has been intruduced late. I would go with 1.4.4

Comment: I'm using 1.7... I'll attempt an upgrade to 1.8 tonight and report the results.

Comment: Have you tried on RTM of Windows 8? Additionally, what if you force a Garbage Collect?